Different mylatexformat.fmt precompiled preamble depending on OS
Is anything like the following possible?
\usepackage{ifplatform}
\ifthenelse{\ifwindows}{%&C:\Users\...\mylatexformat}{%&/Users/.../mylatexformatMAC}

No. 1. The shebang interpretation is before any code expansion. 2. Comments are ignored while code expansion, therefore everything after the first % would be ignored.

It's hard to guess what you would want the syntax to mean. \usepackage is an undefined command until a format has been read but then you want to insert a magic comment changing the format after that? That can not possibly work, not only can the comment syntax not work, you can not change the loaded format after you execute any commands.
If in the (extremely rare) cases that you do want a different format on different platforms it's usually possible to simply use a path that is interpreted differently eg ~/myformat would be the myformat in the users home directory on each platform (kpathsearch interprets ~ as home directory even on Windows) so you can have different format files at that location on each machine.

Sorry, I do not understand completely. My problem is the following:
I have many .tex files in many different folders and want to precompile my preamble. I work on Mac and PC with the same files (synced). So it would be great if there was any possibility to use the same file on Mac and on PC. As of now i have to change the order of my first line every time I work on the other system, i.e.
%&C:\Users\...\mylatexformat
on my PC and
%&/Users/.../mylatexformatMAC
on my Mac.

why do you change the file at all rather than simply specifying the format on the commandline? and why do you have different format files on the PC and Mac? @realGottlob

"simply specifying the format on the commandline" Sorry, I did not know that this is possible?!
"different format files on the PC and Mac" Different paths, same file.

@realGottlob specifying the format on the commandline is the standard mechanism that is almost universally used and documented in any tex manual.   Some systems have a magic %& comment but that is non standard and hardly ever used.
